# Cambiar hexadecimal de colors.xml android studio

Tags: java, android, color

Tengo una actividad en la cual necesito cambiar el color a varios elementos, por lo cual hacerlo uno por uno puede resultar un poco tedioso. Estos elementos comparten un denominador común que es el color desde el recurso correspondiente.

¿Es posible cambiar el valor de dicho recurso mediante programación?

Por ejemplo, hacer que:

```
<color name="colorTitle">#212121</color>
```

luego tome otro valor hexadecimal y este aplique a todos los elementos que tienen **colorTitle**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los resources como `R.colors` son generados en tiempo de compilación como constantes por lo que no podrás cambiarlos en tiempo de ejecucion. Lo que puedes hacer es crear una funcion que retorne el color que deseas y que todas las vistas que requieran cambiar el color dinamicamente lo obtengan por medio al metodo.

Por ejemplo.
Crea una clase `Activity` base para toda tu aplicación que contenga el siguiente metodo:

```
public ActivityBase extends AppCompactActivity
{

  private boolean colorClaro = false;

  public int obtenerColorDinamico()
  {
       if(colorClaro)
       {
          return super.getColor(R.colors.color_claro);
       }
       else{
          return super.getColor(R.colors.color_oscuro);
       }
  }
}
```

Entonces siempre que una vista requiera que el color cambie, entonces solo le asignas el resultado de la funcion, por ejemplo aun `TextView`:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActivityBase
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity);

        myTextView.setTextColor(obtenerColorDinamico());
        //...
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo, el color de los `TextView` estan en base al estado de la variable `colorClaro`, si esta cambiase, cuando cargue la vista de nuevo cambiaran todos los elementos que obtenga el color de la funcion.

El estado que decidirá  si tomar un color o el otro lo pudieras guardar en un `SharePreferences` o base datos o según tu elijas.

Comment: Gracias, una solución interesante y simple.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Es posible cambiar el valor de dicho recurso mediante programación?

**NO, Los elementos definidos en los archivos de recursos por ejemplo `colors.xml`, son de solo lectura.**

Como opción puedes agregar otros colores relacionados, y usar el que decidas por ejemplo:

```
<color name="colorTitle">#212121</color>
<color name="colorTitle_claro">#D9D9D9</color>
<color name="colorTitle_oscuro">#0D0D0D</color>
```